# Probably of revealing 3-same, in a set of 9, composed of 3 sets of 3, by selecting 4.

Tags: probability

First - thanks for helping.  I'm admittedly a bit rusty in probability.  University is so far back!

In what looks like a traditional lotto game; I have a grid of 9 circles.  On this grid, there are 3 blue, red, and white circles -- each covered with that silvery scratch-off stuff that gets all over the place!

I fervently scratch 4 circles at random, hopeful to reveal 3 identical circles.

What is the probability that I win?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Any thoughts of your own on this? Usually that makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hint:  Suppose the disks are numbered, $1,\cdots , 9$.  Now, there are $\binom 94 = 126$ equally probable ways to pick $4$ disks to scratch.  How many include $3$ blues, say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{9}{4}$ possible ways to pick $4$ circles in general, so this is the denominator of our probability. The numerator is the number of ways to pick a winning set of $4$ circles.

There are $3$ ways to pick which color we win with. After picking those three circles with the same color, that leaves us with $6$ circles where the color won't match anything.

All in all, the probability is:

$$P = \frac{3 \cdot 6}{\binom{9}{4}} = \frac{1}{7}$$

Comment: This would theoretically be: ((3C3 + 3C3 + 3C3) * (6C1)) / 9C4   is that right?

Comment: That is equal to $1/7$ as well, yes

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1. Calculate the number of ways that you can choose 4 positions from nine (where order doesn't matter).
2. Count the number of ways you can win. If you have three the same, then one must be different. If you pick the three blues, then the other one is a red or a white. So that's six combinations (because you have your choice of three reds and three whites that can go in the fourth spot). How many more are there?
3. Divide the number of winning combinations by the total number of possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing out all the different possibilities and then finding the probability of each individual possibility